# Can I turn off the FreeDOS command-line beeps?

Tags: freedos

When I try to tab-complete to something with more or less than one possible expansion for instance the FreeDOS command-line (command.com or its equivalent) beeps at me through the PC speaker. Is there a way to configure it to not do that at all or switch to a visual bell or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The only effective solution I found is hacking command.com.

See: https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/mailman/message/37009048/

The thread where this solution is posted:
https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/mailman/freedos-devel/thread/CAJn4PHSbM9Jw3MAFJz58rU1apj7UpEH-jp_FgOGZkFTEjhmKTw@mail.gmail.com/